# Razor Page Unclosed Image Tag

Tags: c#, .net, razor, razor-pages

During a recent deployment we had a Razor web page fail with a compilation error due to an unclosed image tag in a conditional:

```
@if(someValue) {
  <img src="xxx">
}
```

The error indicated an unbalanced bracket in the conditional due to Razor not seeing the image tag as closed, which is understandable.  However, this code ran fine in my development environment as well as in the peer reviewers environment.  Visual Studio gave no indication about this problematic code.  This issue only appeared in our pre-deployment environment.  Since we never deployed to prod I'm not sure if it would have failed there.

My question is, why would this work on some machines and not others?  We try to make all of our environments the same, so obviously something is out of whack.  Could this be a setting I'm missing?  A variance in the framework?  This is quite perplexing.

Comment: AFAIK this is always wrong, is it possible that during development and peer review that the code was set to compile when used, and in the release build it was set to always pre-compile all Razor pages?

Comment: What's odd is that the page ran in dev without error.  If it was a JIT vs pre- compile diff I'd expect the page to fail in dev when it was hit.  I'll make sure to recheck this to make sure.